# Vector Magnitude Equality

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I'm trying to show that:

$$(\nabla \times n)^2=(n \cdot \nabla \times n)^2+(n \times \nabla \times n)^2$$

I know that $n$ is a unit vector and that $-n$ is effectively the same as $n$ for the situation I'm dealing with. I've tried total expansion but nothing cancels out. Through this I've isolated the terms I need for the equality, but there are extra terms associated with each of those. Are there any formulas I can use for curl, cross product, etc? Or is there some trick I can use here?

Comment: Express the curl in terms of the Levi-Civita epsilon-symbol and use the properties of the latter. See www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucappgu/levi-civita.html By the way, it seems that the first term on the right vanishes since the vectors between parentheses are orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\nabla \times n=v$ and recall that $|n\cdot v|=|n||v|\cos\theta$, while
$|n\times v|=|n||v|\sin\theta$ (where $\theta$ is the angle between $n$ and $v$). Then your equality immediately follows.